# How to enable a select dropdown element once the first dropdown element value has been chosen (with CSS)

Tags: css, forms

I've seen multiple ways involving JS/Jquery that allow enabling a second select element (from a disabled state) once the first select element option has been chosen, but I am wondering if anyone can share how to accomplish this with CSS.

Someone I follow on Twitter posted that there was a way to do it but I can't recall the syntax. Can anyone help?

[Image: **Area of Issue** should be disabled until the **How can we help you** value has been chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkGjL.png) Currently, the second dropdown has no values in it until the first dropdown value has been chosen.